# How to implement Column Resizing in a Data Table in Lightning Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds, datatable

Is there any kind of JS function that we can leverage to allow resizing of a column in lightning component? Using 3rd party jQuery libraries are too funky with Locker Service, they would work one day, and next day we realize it is broken. I was wondering, how Standard Lists are able to do resizing on the fly for SLDS data tables?

Comment: I use an appExchange app for a list that I need extended functionality, it has column resizing. It is in a managed package so the code is hidden, but works good: [Lightning DataTable Dev](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000E9TBZUA3)

Comment: The app though has Datatables JS as 3rd party library to handle the table features. And I've read numerous posts in forums that Locker Service is used to break libraries randomly with fresh updates so no guarantee it would work ... :(

Comment: It does work for me for 3 months now